# R: using predict() on new data with high dimensionality

Tags: r, warnings, lm, predict

So the example code that I want to use to make my question clear is the last chunk seen here. 
Basically, my understanding from similar threads that I've found on here is that in order to use a model to predict from a new data set, you must have the same variable names in the new data set as the data that you used in your initial model. Running my example code will produce the following message:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 10 rows but variable(s) found have 100 rows
```

The obvious answer in this simple case is to write something like:

```
model = lm(Y ~ A + B + C, data = newdata)
```

And then make the column names in newdata.2 the same as they were in newdata.

However, this isn't really a practical option when the number of predictor variables is relatively large (say 50 or 100). Is there a good way to handle this using the standard predict() and lm() functions in R?

```
## Generate Predictor variables
A = rnorm(100)
B = rnorm(100)
C = rnorm(100)

X = cbind(A,B,C)
X.design = model.matrix(~ X)

## Create Response variable
beta.star = c(0,0,1,2)
Y = X.design %*% beta.star + rnorm(100)

## Mock data.frame
newdata = data.frame(cbind(Y,X))
colnames(newdata) = c("Y","A","B","C")  

## Fit model
m1 = lm(Y ~ X.design - 1, data  = newdata)

## create mock new data 
d = rnorm(10)
e = rnorm(10)
f = rnorm(10)

newdata.2 = data.frame(cbind(d,e,f))

## Predict new data
predict(m1, newdata = newdata.2)
```

Hopefully this was all clear enough. I appreciate the help!

Comment: If you just want to include "all the variables" in your regression, you don't need to use a design matrix, just use `lm(Y ~ . - 1, data  = newdata)`. And you really do need to match up variable names when using predict, but you could set them fairly easily with `setNames(newdata.2, attr(terms(m1),"term.labels"))`

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me crazy.